# Serving JSPs with HttpServlet as sole entry point

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have a Java EE site with JSPs, set up with an MVC architecture. I have servlets pointing to a model object, and I've chosen one servlet, the NewspaperServlet, to be the sole entry point for HTTP requests. From there, I call my other servlets as necessary. I want to have RESTful URLs, so http://myurl/ serves up /index.jsp, http://myurl/article/1 serves /article.jsp and the Article object with id 1, and so on.

I'm processing the path just fine, but when it comes time to actually serve my JSP pages, I'm redirecting myself right back into my code, because I try and retrieve, say, /index.jsp and because my code is the sole entry point, it then calls my code looking for how to serve /index.jsp! Should I be resorting to opening my files and outputting the contents, or is there a more sane way of doing this?

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" 
id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>wsd-newspaper</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>


  <servlet>
  <servlet-name>JSP Web Service</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>
   merus.newspaper.NewspaperServlet
  </servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>

 <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>JSP Web Service</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

NewspaperServlet.doGet():

```
public void doGet(  HttpServletRequest request,
                    HttpServletResponse response) 
throws ServletException, IOException {

    String pathInfo = request.getPathInfo();
    request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    response.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/html");

    //index
    if (pathInfo.equalsIgnoreCase("/")) {
        request.setAttribute("articleList", controller.getIndex());
        RequestDispatcher dp = request.getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp");
        dp.forward(request, response);

    }

    //article servlet redirect
    if (pathInfo.startsWith("/article") || 
        pathInfo.startsWith("/archive")) {
        articleServlet.doGet(request, response);
        return;
    }

    //author servlet redirect
    if (pathInfo.startsWith("/author")) {
        authorServlet.doGet(request, response);
        return;
    }

    if (pathInfo.startsWith("/logout")) {
        request.getSession().removeAttribute("user");
    }


    RequestDispatcher dp = request.getRequestDispatcher("/404.html");
    dp.include(request, response);
}
```

Notes: because of the peculiarities of the model I'm required to work with, I want to be very careful I don't load it twice. The NewspaperServlet creates and initialises the other servlets so it can also be the only class that loads the model.

The controller is separate from the servlet. The controller is intended to be used to provide a web service, which will necessitate another endpoint in web.xml. I'm not attached to having one endpoint as much as I want RESTful URLs.

Answer (score 0):

Change your url pattern to

```
<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
```

This is the fallback pattern. If the container cannot find any other match with other mapped servlets, it will fall back to this one.

Most (if not all) servlet contains register a `Servlet` which handles JSP with the pattern

```
<url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
```

This will match before your `/`.

Comment: I can't find an example of the JSP handling you reference here; the vast majority of the examples I see assume it handles automagically if you send requests to the JSP files directly, which I'm not doing because in accordance with MVC I don't want requests to go to views except through controllers.

Comment: The only thing you need is the [specification](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/servlet-3.0-fr-oth-JSpec/). Chapter 12 explains the types of mappings and the order in which they are checked. You'll notice it checks path mapping (`/*`) before doing extension mapping (`*.wtv`). If you're using Tomcat, you can find a registered `JspServlet` in the root `web.xml`. For other containers, they'll probably have one too, you'll just have to find it.